# @HTML.CheckBoxFor() MVC 3.0 Issue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkboxfor

I have a loop that generates List of items with Check box to select

```
foreach(var i in item)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>i.Checked)
    @Html.labelfor(x=>i.price)
}
```

I have 3 items. so this is Producing below code three times

```
<input id="paid" name="paid" value="true" type="checkbox">
<input name="paid" value="false" type="hidden">
```

Now when i try to access the checked prices in my controller

```
string[] paid = Request.Form["paid"].split(',');
```

I should receive 3 values of true/false, irrespective of how many prices were check by the user

Instead, it returns 3+ as many as user checked. Lets say if user check one price then in my controller. I will receive 3+1= 4 true/false values.

How can i get rid of this issue?

Comment: All that i am trying to achieve is: if user check First price in the list of 3 prices. I would like to access that price in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this post. http://forums.asp.net/t/1314753.aspx

Comment: to an extent it is same. But IT is more than that. what I need is if my for loop renders 4 checkboxs then I need only 4 true/false values to my controller nothing more than that. But for now i got it worked with a duplicating string array with a ArralyList and if (condition). I believe that is not a right way to do.